# return from a launched activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to play a video using intents with the following code :

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/ted.mp4");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

This bit works fine but I doesn't return to the previous activity when the back button is pressed.
The first time it just restarts the video, but if it is pressed another time (on some devices 3 times) it will return to the previous activity (my main activity).

And I must mention that I don't mean quick successive clicks of the back button.

So how can I fix it, and why is it acting like this ?

Comment: it does depends on the App that it opens, for example with MX Player, the back button works without a problem. Maybe the app you open overrides the back button methods.

Comment: I've tried with MX Player, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this way it may help you,

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/ted.mp4");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/mp4");
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Figured I have to add the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and it will do the trick